# how to change the attribute of an object after n seconds using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, settimeout, simulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn8MI.png)https://github.com/sarang997/simulation1
Here is the simulation I am working on. You can try running the html file for it to work. There are circles colliding with each other in the simulation. Whenever a red circle collides with the green circle it changes the color of the green circle to red. Now what I want is as soon as the circle turns red I want a timer which changes its color to blue after n seconds. I am not able to achieve this.

There is a section in the shapes.js file where collision between the circles is detected and thats where I am changing the colors and thats exactly where I want the timer to start. (line 104 and 110 in shapes.js file)

Comment: https://github.com/sarang997/simulation1  404 Not found. Please add [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem you can loop it as well if you want the circle to continue changing colors (here replaced by console.log). N is here equal to seconds, it's multiplied by 1000 as setTimeout uses milliseconds by default.

```js
   function changeColor(seconds) {
        setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('Here the circle would change color.');  
        }, seconds*1e3);
    }
    changeColor(3)
```